# Why is this string replace function not affecting numbers?

Tags: php, string

I have the following code:

```
$badChars = array("W", "X", "Y", "0");
$goodChars = array("A", "B", "C", "1");
$string = str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, $string);
```

When I look at `$string`, I can see that W, X, and Y have been replaced with A, B, and C, as hoped. But `$string` still contains zeros.

I thought it might be some kind of string/integer confusion, so I also tried:

```
$badChars = array("W", "X", "Y", 0);
$goodChars = array("A", "B", "C", 1);
```

... but it made no difference.

Why are the numbers being ignored by `str_replace()`?

Comment: Is that a typo in your question or is your code defective? Missing `"`before the W in your first array.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please show a complete (non) working example. http://codepad.viper-7.com/abrssq

Comment: Works for me... What is the `$string` you're trying to run the function on?

Comment: Now I'm confused. I changed the code to use str_ireplace(), and it worked. Which I thought was odd. So I changed it back to str_replace, and now that works too. :-/ I don't know how to call this one. I *swear* this was being weird for the last hour or so... but given the answers, maybe it was some typo that I inadvertently corrected...? Do I mark one of the answers as correct or close the question as "too localized"? What's the right protocol?

Comment: Dave, I'll vote to close as too localised,  due to the fact that "this question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" includes the "extraordinarily narrow situation" that is PEBKAC :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it works at all the way you have it (or, since you edited the question, the way you *had* it, which was a non-returning `str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, $string);`). `str_replace` *returns* the modified string:

```
$string = str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, $string);
```

Other than that, the code is fine. Using the test code:

```
<?php
    $string = "WAIT XEROX YETI 1234567890";
    $badChars = array("W", "X", "Y", "0");
    $goodChars = array("A", "B", "C", "1");
    $string = str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, $string);
    var_dump($string);
?>
```

You get:

```
string(26) "AAIT BEROB CETI 1234567891"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine. http://codepad.viper-7.com/4gpNbi

Answer (score 1):

```
$badChars = array("W", "X", "Y", "0");
$goodChars = array("A", "B", "C", "1");
echo str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, "WXY0 ABC1 lol");
```

The result of this code is : ***ABC1 ABC1 lol***

So it seems your code is correct, the only flaw is probably that the replace function itself returns a string, its not ***a mutator method***. You should likely access like:

```
$val = str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, "WXY0 ABC1 lol");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me remind you that `str_replace()` does not modify original string but returns a modified one:

```
<?php
$badChars = array("W", "X", "Y", "0");
$goodChars = array("A", "B", "C", "1");
echo str_replace ($badChars, $goodChars, 'WXY0');
```

returns `ABC1` as you may expect.